# Hive SQL logic - case when statement

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, case-statement, hive-query

### My query:

```
case 
   when upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event%" and (upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-WBR%" or upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-Webinar%") THEN "Field"
   else "Demand"
end as Tactic
```

Desired Output:

```
Event-WBR = Demand
Event = Field
```

Actual Output:

```
Event-WBR = Field
Event = Field
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should replace the 'or' with 'and'

```
case 
       when upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event%" and (upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-WBR%" and upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-Webinar%") THEN "Demand"
       else "Field"
    end as Tactic
```

But here another 2 other options:

If you only want to do for the word 'Event', you can do something like this

```
case 
   when upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event" and (upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-WBR%" or upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-Webinar%") THEN "Demand"
   else "Field"
end as Tactic
```

If you want to exclude these 2 words only, you can do like this.

```
case 
   when upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event-WBR%" or (upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event-Webinar%" THEN "Field"
   else "Demand"
end as Tactic
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `when`s :

```
(case when (upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-WBR%" or 
            upper(a.camp_name) not like "%Event-Webinar%"
           ) then 'Event'
      when upper(a.camp_name) like "%Event%" then 'Event'
      else 'Deman'
 end) as tactic
```